Проблема с работой Anti-AFK
Делаю Anti-AFK для игры чтобы не вылетало. Беда вот в чем, надо нажимать пробел, но вот увы, в чате (по сути в текст боксах) все работает хорошо, да только сам персонаж не прыгает, вот код
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    private const byte VK_SPACE = 0x20;
    const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0;
    const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    }

    private void gunaButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Включаем/отключаем таймер
        if (!timer.Enabled)
        {
            timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 5000; // Задержка в миллисекундах (5 секунд)
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Отправляем нажатие пробела
        SendSpacebarKeyDown();

        // Отправляем отпускание пробела
        SendSpacebarKeyUp();
    }

    private void SendSpacebarKeyDown()
    {
        keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private void SendSpacebarKeyUp()
    {
        keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}

